# Remove space in Stack

Tags: flutter, dart, stack, card

I want to place Card below the 4 icons, but why there is a big gap between?

```
    case ConnectionState.active:
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return SingleChildScrollView(
                        child: Column(children: [
                      Stack(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            height: 500,
                          ),
                          Positioned(
                              top: 0,
                              left: 0,
                              right: 0,
                              child: Container(height: 50, color: Colors.orange)),
                          Positioned(
                            top: 0,
                            left: 24,
                            right: 24,
                            child: Card(
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                side: BorderSide(color: Colors.white70, width: 1),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                              ),
                              margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                              child: _showWidget(
                                  snapshot.data!), // this are the 4 icons code
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      _showBelowCard(snapshot.data!),  // card below 4 icons
                    ]));
                  } else {
                    return NoItem();
                  }


 Widget _showBelowCard(ABC abc) {
    return Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: const [
          Text(
            "Place it below 4 icons",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20),
          Text(
            "Status",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
          ),
        ]);
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Try to reduce container height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it is way down is due to the `Container()` with the height of 500 on your `Stack()`. The `Stack()` widget usually takes the size of the biggest children.

And if you want to have some space between the `Card()` and the `Stack()` just add `SizedBox()` with your desired height.

Comment: how to fix? I need to add 3 more card below the 4 icons. The whole screen should be able to scroll.

Comment: just add the 3 more cards since it is already wrap with the SingleChildScrollView() widget it will have scroll functionality once it takes up the entire screen.

Comment: the 3 card should add inside Stack?

Comment: Just put it outside the Stack() and make it one of children of the Column() just like the code you have at the top.